# Which preposition should I use?

Tags: indefinite-articles

Dop I use a or an in the following sentence.

You are invited to attend **a** European Festival

or You are invited to attend **an** European festival

Comment: This question belongs in http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You confuse prepositions as in/on/at and the two indefinite articles a/an. Try to learn the basic grammar terms for word classes, sentence parts, and verb forms. Please change your headline.

Comment: See  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260200/a-an-confusion-with-words-starting-with-u-o

Answer (score 0):

1. *a* and *an* are indefinite articles, not prepositions.
2. You use the one that makes sense when you read the phrase out loud. In this case, you use *a* because *European* is pronounced as if it begins with a consonant (sounding like *y* as in *yellow*) and not as if it begins with a vowel.